# Limiting page navigation options in datatables

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking to customized the output of a data table in one of my shiny applications. I'd like to only keep the "next page" button on the bottom of the data table, but cannot figure out how to do so. I know you can customize the output using options = list(dom = ...) but cannot figure out how to produce the output I would like. Is this something that will only be able to be accomplished using java script? Example below, where Previous 1, 2, etc. is what I would like to keep. Thank you!

```
library(DT)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput(outputId = "dat")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  tb = iris
  tb = datatable(tb, list(pageLength = 10))

  output$dat = renderDataTable({
      tb
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn about all datatable options see [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/) (datatables documentation). The option you are interested in is [pagingType](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType). So just do

```
library(DT)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "dat")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    tb = iris
    tb = DT::datatable(tb, list(pageLength = 10,pagingType = 'simple'))

    output$dat = DT::renderDataTable(
        {tb}
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```